# How i can convert my html to back WMD editor?

Tags: text-editor, rich-text-editor, wmd, wmd-editor

I have already html in my database and i want to use wmd editor, but when i get html from database wmd editor showing html in wmd editor, but i want wmd style html. like for bold ** bold **. Any one have solution.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to either store both the raw markdown and HTML, or just reprocess the markdown every time you need it.